# devices going silent and not responding to ping - android

Tags: android, networking, router, icmp, arp

I am making an app to search devices connected to my Wifi modem.I am working on it for a while and there are quiet a few question's on the topic but nothing which answers my question.

I have been trying to find devices by using the ARP table,Inetaddress's isReachable command , and also using /system/bin/ping and it works "fine" but there are periods in which certain devices (especially mobile and tab's) go silent and not respond to any kind of contact we try to make using the above methods . This period of "silence" could last upto around a minute which is bad for my project .

I am using Java to code.I am not finding any other path forward on this . Any help is Appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is the normal behavior of an android system.

When a device is in lock mode (and not only) the OS, and as OS you should consider not only the android version but also any changes made by the device constructor, could pause/slow down various operations to conserve battery.

How aggressive is the pause/slow down can vary from device to device and from OS version to OS version. For example, version 6 of Android is more aggressive on preserve battery from former versions.

You have also to consider that the user has the possibility to close the wifi (via settings) when the screen goes off.

You have to deal with this as it is a prerequisite condition for your app.

Comment: Hey  . But there are certain app's like "Fing" which is perfect . It always manages to find all devices always . This is how i believe there is a way to do this.

Comment: The app you mentioned maybe inquire only the router and not the single devices. My app, for example, check the connection between the devices via socket and in that case the responsiveness of the device is not constant. Be aware that no one here will give you the code for create a Fing like app but will only help you to debug your code. If you need a specific answer you have to include the code that creates you an issue.

Comment: I was able to find results with some experiments that they are connecting to individual devices . I don't think there is a way to inquire about this to the router . What do you feel ?